# How to get Tailwind config from an url in postcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, config, postcss

I'm trying to use a Tailwind config and multiple CSS files from a different repo (eventually a separate package).

I'm using Tailwind with PostCSS.

Could someone point me to the correct way to get JS/CSS from a URL?

This didn't work:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {config: 'https://github.com/dnlklmn/polkadot-theme/blob/main/tailwind.config.cjs'},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```